# How do I create a link trail for sub paths in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How can I create a trail for the sub paths of my website like this:

> Home > Games > Simple > Tictactoe

Above is for the link localhost:3000/Games/Simple/Tictactoe
Where pressing any of those buttons will take you to their respective URL, such as if I clicked `Games` it will take me to localhost:3000/Games.

I know it can be hardcoded but that won't be scalable.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to manipulate the paths to generate what you want accordingly

Example code:
Given the path `site.com/Games/Simple/Tictactoe`

```
export default function Breadcrumbs(){
  // take the pathname
  const pathname = usePathname()

  // first you'll need to separate each route but first you need to strip the first slash
  const paths = pathname?.replace("/").split("/")

  let previousRoute = '' // creating this to hold previous route
  // Now loop through the array to build an array of links
  const links = paths. Map((path, index) => {
    // first hold the value adding a slash
    previousRoute += path + "/"

    return index < (paths.length - 2) 
      ? (
           <>
             <Link href={previousRoute}>
               {path}
             </Link>
             <span>{" > "}</span>
           </>
  )
      : <span>{path}</span>
  }) // Link is the NextJS component
  // Important: paths.length - 2 because the last is the actual page so we don't want another link

  return links
}

//usage
<Breadcrumbs />
// This should render something like
// Games > Simple > Tictactoe
// Games and Simple will be clickable and should redirect you to the correct route
```